# Scala Parser - Message Length

Tags: parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I'm toying with Scala's Parser library.  I am trying to write a parser for a format where a length is specified followed by a message of that length.  For example:

```
x.parseAll(x.message, "5helloworld") // result: "hello", remaining: "world"
```

I'm not sure how to do this using combinators.  My mind first goes to:

```
def message = length ~ body
```

But obviously body depends on length, and I don't know how to do that :p

Instead you could just define a message Parser as a single Parser (not combination of Parsers) and I think that is doable (although I haven't looked if a single Parser can pull several elem?).

Anyways, I'm a scala noob, I just find this awesome :)

Comment: Both answers helpful, thanks.  I am still learning how to think in scala way which is why this question is dubious :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `into` for that, or its abbreviation, `>>`:

```
scala> object T extends RegexParsers {
     |   def length: Parser[String] = """\d+""".r
     |   def message: Parser[String] = length >> { length => """\w{%d}""".format(length.toInt).r }
     | }
defined module T

scala> T.parseAll(T.message, "5helloworld")
res0: T.ParseResult[String] =
[1.7] failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but `w' found

5helloworld
      ^

scala> T.parse(T.message, "5helloworld")
res1: T.ParseResult[String] = [1.7] parsed: hello
```

Be careful with precedence when using it. If you add an "~ remainder" after the function above, for instance, Scala will interpret it as `length >> ({ length => ...} ~ remainder)` instead of `(length >> { length => ...}) ~ remainder`.

Answer (score 2):

This does not sound like a context free language, so you will need to use flatMap :

```
def message = length.flatMap(l => bodyOfLength(n))
```

where length is of type Parser[Int] and bodyOfLength(n) would be based on repN, such as

```
def bodyWithLength(n: Int) : Parser[String] 
  = repN(n, elem("any", _ => true)) ^^ {_.mkString}
```

Comment: So this makes sense to me, and I got it working on the above example.  But how do I 'know' that flatMap on Parser[Int] makes use of 'get()' (or whatever it is doing to get the Int result from the Parser[Int])?  This may be a poorly worded question :)

Comment: okay ... parser source code: http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_7_1_final/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.scala?view=markup -- has definition of flatMap on Parser which calls flatMapWithNext on ParseResult ... fascinating.

Comment: Actually, the signature alone gives a lot: in Parser[T], `flatMap[T](f: T => Parser[U]) : Parser[U]`. When parsing, it will return U. With what is in context, `this` and `f`, the only way to parse to a U is by applying a parser returned by `f`. To get it, `f` must be called, and for that, a `T` arg is needed. The only way to get a `T` is to apply `this`. Daniel is correct that it may be better to use the synonym "into" rather than flatMap. flatMap is the usual name for function with this signature in scala. into is clearer in context, and happens to be properly documented in scaladoc.

Comment: Thanks again for the response.  C# is my main language, I just happened upon scala when learning actors and now keep falling further into the rabbit hole learning the functional side (every time I think I 'get' monads I learn that I don't).  I should just try it out, but knowing that flatMap is defined could this be done as something like `for { n <- length; m <- bodyWithLength(n); } yield (m)` (obviously non working code, I'm just not sure how to wire it up in my head).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn´t use pasrer combinators for this purpose. But if you have to or the problem becomes more complex you could try this:

```
def times(x :Long,what:String) : Parser[Any] = x match {
case 1 => what;
case x => what~times(x-1,what);
}
```

Don´t use parseAll if you want something remained, use parse.
You could parse length, store the result in a mutable field x(I know ugly, but useful here) and parse body x times, then you get the String parsed and the rest remains in the parser.